# Hide div onscroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, hide, onscroll

I have a div that I need to hide on scroll up and down if it has classes 1 and 2 since those classes show up the div on the page.

```html
<div id="mydiv" class="class1 class2">MyContent</div>
```

How do I reach that?

Thank you

Comment: Please be clearer, and show some minimal code to explain your situation.

Comment: I have a dropdown list which activates by clicking on <a> button, the need is to get rid of the dropdown list just by scrolling up and down without need to press on the same <a> button to make it disappear, thanks

Comment: Is your dropdown made by any external plugin/library or manually ?

Comment: yes, it is used by bootstrap 4

Comment: Should I paste 11 lines of the whole button code if it can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap had `show` class on `dropdown-menu` element while it's open. You should just remove this class when `window.onscroll` is fired.

```js
window.onscroll = (e) => {
  var dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-menu");
  for (var i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
    dropdowns[i].classList.remove("show");
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div>
<p>
  BLANK<br/><br/><br/>
  BLANK<br/><br/><br/>
  BLANK<br/><br/><br/>
</p>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
    <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Action</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Another action</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Something else here</button>
  </div>
</div>
<p>
  BLANK<br/><br/><br/>
  BLANK<br/><br/><br/>
  BLANK<br/><br/><br/>
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe it's also known how to make the click on <a> Bootstrap 4 button in mobile Safari so it activates after the first click, not the second which calls popups the safari top and bottom menus? thanks

Comment: Oh I found that moving up the button a bit above fixed this mobile safari issue, thanks